# Can I publish my book (paperback) using createSpace if I already initiated paperback and published Kindle edition in Amazon?

Tags: kindle, ebook-readers, amazon

I have published my [ebook](https://www.amazon.in/Job-Rule-World-Akhil-Gupta-ebook/dp/B075MQCF82/) in all Amazon websites (US UK DE FR ES IT NL JP BR CA MX AU IN). I also initiated paperback through Amazon.

Unfortunately for Amazon India paperback option was not available. So I searched all over places and found we have to go using [CreateSpace](https://www.createspace.com/) to make my paperbook available in India.

Now my question is can i initiate my paperback in createSpace also as paperback in Amazon status as "Publishing"

Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if Createspace works in India, but Amazon controls that company too.

It's fairly easy to find a local company produce the print books somewhere to be sold on Amazon.

In my opinion, I would focus exclusively on ebooks because the author has more control over what price to give it (and can receive a higher percentage of the profits). When I published 2 createspace books, I found that the prices you were allowed to set was way too high to make it competitive.